# How To Stop Recording Music by Gracenote SDK in iOS

Tags: ios5, ios4, sdk, xcode4.2, gracenote

Currently I'm using the "GN_Music_SDK_iOS" SDK in my iPhone App. I just started recording music using the `[GNOperations recognizeMIDStreamFromMic:responseObject config:config];` method, then it is giving recording status by `GNStatusChanged:` method. But according to my application requirements, I need to stop the recording myself, that is by clicking some button. How can I stop the recording of music and continue our searching using the Gracenote SDK?

Comment: would you provide me download link for "GN_Music_SDK_iOS" sdk.
when i download from "https://developer.gracenote.com/gnsdk" link not able to unzip sdk.

please help me provide me SDK if you have.

Answer (score 0):

In the Gracenote SDK they just call [GNOperations cancelAll]; from a button IBAction to cancel listening. Is there something else you wanted besides this?

Comment: Cancel is not the way to go here. The recognizeMIDStreamFromMic function does all by itself. Recording enough audio, making the query and returning a result.